# Why can't I predict new data using SVM and KNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, knn

I'm new to machine learning and I just learned KNN and SVM with sklearn. How do I make a prediction for new data using SVM or KNN? I have tried both to make prediction. They make good prediction only when the data is already known. But when I try to predict new data, they give an incorrect prediction.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

x=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11]], dtype=np.float64)
y=np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], dtype=np.float64)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(x, y)
print(clf.predict([[20]]))
print(clf.score(x, y))
```

0utput:

```
[12.]
1.0
```

This code will make a good prediction as long as the data to predict is within the range x_train. But when I try to predict for example 20, or anything above the range x_train, the output will always be 12 which is the last element of y. I don't know what I do wrong in the code.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. A classification model will naturally think that anything above the `x` range should belong to the highest class of `y`, because of the clear correlation. I understand that your intention is regression, not classification. Therefore check out resources on Support Vector Regression.

Comment: I didn't know there is Support Vector Regression. Thanks so much for the info. But why is the accuracy is not 1.0? When I try it with LinearRegression it correctly predicts 51.0 for x is 50 with 1.0 accuracy. While with svm.SVR it gives me 50.12 with 0.9996 accuracy? Is it not better than LinearRegression?

Comment: @NuhYamin Your notion of "better" is biased by your intuition. Nothing intrinsically makes one learned function "better" than another if they both model their training data well. The issue is an SVR is a higher capacity model than LinearRegression, and in fact your data are generated from a simple, deterministic linear relationship. Thus a linear model will converge to fit faster than SVR. If the data comes from a more complex distribution, SVR may be better. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a regression model rather than a classification model. For svm based regression use svm.SVR()

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

x=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11]], dtype=np.float64)
y=np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], dtype=np.float64)

clf = svm.SVR(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(x, y)
print(clf.predict([[50]]))
print(clf.score(x, y))
```

output:

```
[50.12]
0.9996
```

Comment: Hi, AILearning, thank you so much. That really helps.

Answer (score 3):

The code is behaving as mathematically described by a support vector machine.

You must understand how your data are being interpreted by the algorithm. You have 11 data points, and you are giving each one a different *class*. The SVM ends up basically dividing the number line into 11 segments (for the 11 *classes* you defined):

`data = [(x, clf.predict([[x]])[0]) for x in np.linspace(1, 20, 300)]
plt.scatter([p[0] for p in data], [p[1] for p in data])
plt.show()`

[image: SVM classes]

The answer by AILearning tells you how to fit your given toy problem, but make sure you also understand why your code wasn't doing what you thought it was. For any finite set of examples there are infinitely many functions that fit the data. Your fundamental issue is you are confusing regression and classification. From the sounds of it, you *want* a simple regression model to extrapolate a fit function from the data points, but your *code* is for a classification model.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks so much. I'm trying to improve my ML knowledge.